# SFTP to read csv file using ssis 2008

Tags: ssis

Can we read a csv file from SFTP folder location without downloading it anywhere on local?
 I can use FTP task component but it will download file locally, i want to read file from sftp itself.
Is it possible? I am using SSIS 2008.

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

In general, FTP does not allow to read file directly from remote ftp server without downloading it to local folder. You have to download/copy this file to local folder for further processing.

you can delete this locally downloaded file after processing it.

But I would like to know why you decided to read it directly? Any specific reason.

There is another approach using script task. [you need to write code to download the file into filestream using FTPWebRequest class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx) in ssis script editor.

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, Thanks for update.We took this approach because client dont want to expose file locally at all. Might be misused.